# core 2.1, react, signalR connection error

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, signalr, expo

ChatScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, AsyncStorage, Platform, KeyboardAvoidingView, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { Header } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import moment from 'moment';
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';

export default class ChatScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        }

    state = {
        username: '',
        seq: '',
        messages: [{
            _id: 1,
            text: 'Hello developer',
            createdAt: moment.utc().format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss").toString(),//new Date(),
            user: {
                _id: 2,
                name: 'React',
                avatar: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAYAAAAehFoBAAAJhklEQVR4Ab2XA5gky7ZG1x+RmYXW2Lpjz7Nt27Zt27Zt2/a7PjZGR90z0y51ZcS+WZkHo66uvgfr65X4EPHXrt27owUvnisf8q9HTTqJcUhwANgMIHEtRi4gHhN2P/AwLxIVm/HmENGHqRDs3UGHwagQ1yPAsOeeHgX9J8ZfQem60cwH/zvrQf3kc62WfzWmY7wIBA9Z3/8o8MvrC/z+/80oWGIfj+y7wY4AYOJFIQPA0KMyfQvwh4xAYokxjEiUcL8h+DQMDMcwlIhwdQXM8FtqWDBuiwkAYYeBPzD4YLP46YANDRwtshohhFd55/8WpxMGgBiKE2F2hfTUFCRi5e5F/MYUorEahqjgUzG9TQj5hwCPrxo45IHb0dy772jr4sXX4ZNJY0T6RlyB8U/Zj5tKufpldxF7hlIxEvInLPbvGNt/4G2AR24buLl3PzeTz7b39WZmXu/T+oTJMSpxvkd2dgN+XxM5kZ2ZovuaWfy2OiMh8Gltsjcz/QafTJwBLt4SuAjHzfRa8//rvJ+QTzAzRkGC0DbS01P4DSmxE0mOT2L/OwcSZqMWOSXmYSLvzf8PsPeWwEU4rkdJ9qcuTfeAsAggRiEGw01kZOemsGCwEslOTOA21ogrhhLHKJgBzuOc22OmPwc+kutwRUBesP6xMn2UmcNMGKMb5gPJ4XFqpyaIrYD1IumhMZKDY4T5iKHRtYEemT4C/McW8pzu+pcofi1KGG5d4lwZODszid+SQQQEfnNKWlQ5tCO4kdezShE10H61kOd0zz1ouf7FQuOGw9C6jDloPKX+Dhufn8Wkrqxy/W034LfUCT1GXU+VwnAITfilxhcXMtANLulS0+WT3e8xHKB1m89W1W283RRxIYfEocLYitROjpMeHyfMBUDr1nAU2b7PIVdIeek38o8lJhvK3mWdyhEWI/W3mkSpsL6BE3iQwE0m1E5PELuG6c1Y3xxEP1lk/JhCksElOj4JEyUCjLJS5eZiKJYb1of6W08B1y8hEFg3FoHHy7D9J/soW2tBIBF+KkFeWDRAmOMTgT9KglwC9p5CGEA0MEgPjuHGHSXG7RGEpUC6K6N2dqz6gJnAQCYIhvUHgccY/7Ct9B/vlBVfC+tEwpU+MTdwDgGGvRemROc/8J63Nni9qMiv9qmfG2fPLx/BAsSlHJxYjdgzkk0eeUEEHC9ghkWqSgUjzOWQCIwS6bqvVFU1XcPh6o6nv+48y/88R7ozA8AAwVu7YO4cvDDKNJXSe7TH7K9PIw9uyhPb5Vy90ZXCboR+YbyhF65DSMLMIAIGyoEw0LBAoUEE60eSqaQMu/DHV+nc0cJtyp7PBSKYewsn3JHrR5lqCXgx8wNP8dTXXiTM56Q7MqpetfJeumJlcBy3Hm6s9MZ3/0KlwQAQRvUDyZYUyyPPfOdlnvqWS8S+cM0EQ5VyCHcwMXEQE88TgFpCetCz8FfzdO7tsP2bdzP+LhOEhUBcDuAEGBbB19boc0AIc6BaGbgMjgTRcGNVC3TubvP0tz1B9742tYNNlKjqYXT9+tsc5jbfMkqiynt2pEl+JXDp8y5w5Wdn8FOeZEdaVrjEQHXHUPTCTZlDqYMyMPhNVQvM/vY1LnzK4/TOr1A71sScI1YZbnY8iUisggXwO2qoFZn+yRlar2uz6zt2kR3IyhGFB1dzrIkAAyUqxYFrurLdnvrmp1j4x4Vy0vhJTwzGEOSQFhhy0IkB1PDUDjdYfnWb859xgYV/WCTZmeA3eHCAMRoqg5Yu/3+Lxz7+AvP/sER2pIGbSIiBVXNQ3TvOojsf5YDVNVNprVg4dOHSlz/Jk986jbxYL5Ybz/zoFc5/1mX6VyP1k02o2nB4BhyYm3Fm9kgVam1jLvymDL85Y/7vl+g+1MNWDETpUAQWKULmzP7ZImr6cvrEXCPtbQy0i86U3GtxHefUKPJFY+r9Jkl3p/Qu9svpAauEVmXsRPKZnHRrwoYPniS0RYwa/dxdZkzudoZ7o0krhhhZORpnGyRTHiUin4uFAYuAbv1lC8uxPCBhIC8a5xqo7rG4nj3VG2R1QBv0v4aDEYwdSHemNM/UCK2IasI1ROwaYTYQewai1FaMfD6U1VUi8CrfGycysr0Z+bKNtGeVTf8DdBxA7vVHI35KVmaN+ok69cNZGVK+CuIyYdFQRokZKBPWpwpbQewY2e6U5rk6+YJhumUfqxTXm3v9cSFucKkv1n7b5MKa/x6ZSiffuVFWFTcQoAqVbksI1yIPfdI0D3zE0/Qu56TbqrYhUoEQMP72dZR5Yhy+Z5lJzoqMv1OIG1yAlu+kP2Qmhpm3KL/K8beplX0pT0ky6fBTjoX/6PLAx82w/MY+nYcCD37SDLN/18ZPOPwGhwVA0J8NNI5kZPszwhKstW+R7Qdzr9bzFR6YhPx71mqH/iw0T9WoHUiJbcOAdKtHmbj8Qws8/DnX6M8btUNZaeyJR794lovfPo8SyHZ6LELsVM/N4zXyBTAN2Zcy23cVMtA99wC0BV+HecDdqlXDffytMuQoQ2ZF2M6jOQ9+6jWe+oVWUf2UdHuK5SpNNifUD2ZM/26b+z/2Gst3rlDb46kOQdA4lULiIGqVPT2Cr+2O0SlkoKseKoEfNq87DHGzoTeoSsL4uQyAZIPj2l91eOCTZll8bZ/GsQzV3I2jKgpSR/1oRuuBwIOfOcf077TJtrsydONQQro7IfRWqa7Xnab0Rwp5Tlc+XGe3lb9vntM30w1fVX8OGqezoiVS8oXIY9+4yCNfuYh5UT+cYqv9EbDCIGr7E9yY5/x3LPHoVy3SuxSYfMcazWMp/XluaD0zaZChyPLehVxvMrjcxDXveG/D/xcxIlHixhxhCa78WZfp3+uwdEdO42CKEmG5sRYWwI+L+kHH7D+t0H4ksP0TG/QXq7VBAFhE4PCu/z6+5ma5Cd35PjPcjqktzfeffrL3D1ndASBfzdDe05F0g0g2OQhgrA8BeAiLRn82km1zuKawQMlKN7J9d+0DgH/kNuj8JyyzGtNP9d4nydxfOGmMVwCL1ur340cA/8IqJEUohvAvmJ0y+T8CezteVvRaU/6xSaZLDMElmRgm4qJZ/vag7zApN8RLbA76duDtpeRSIUN9w/suMirO/B4L+uo8DV/qDM+LwLDog/9JiR8DnmBEdMd7t1g3OXvymn0SxocB7wg4RiMArxb6q6TH7wOXWSe6891avBj6dXYReUuMM0ivArYCE1QsGVyR2Xkc9yDuAJ7iRfAmHf/gI2GxdiAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=',
            },
        }],
        signalRConnection: null
    };


    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: (navigation.state.params || {}).key || 'NULL!',
        headerForceInset: { vertical: 'never' }
    });


    _bootstrap = async () => {
        const username = await AsyncStorage.getItem('username');
        this.setState({ name: username });
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log("componentDidMount");
        let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("http://192.168.111.14:5000/api/chat", {
                skipNegotiation: true,
                transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
            })
            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
            .build();

        console.log('what is connection?')

        console.log(connection)


        connection
            .start()
            .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
            .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err));
    }

    onSend(message = []) {
        sendMessage = () => {
            this.state.hubConnection
                .invoke('sendToAll', this.state.nick, this.state.message)
                .catch(err => console.error(err));
        }
    }
    render() 
        const mainContent = (
            <GiftedChat
                messages={this.state.messages}
                onSend={(messages) => this.onSend(messages)}
                user={{ _id: 1 }}
            />
        );
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            return (
                <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }} keyboardVerticalOffset={100} behavior="padding" enabled>
                    {mainContent}
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            );
        } else {
            return (<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                {mainContent}
            </SafeAreaView>)
        }
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
});
```

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CoreServer.Repositories;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace CoreServer {
    public class Startup {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup (IConfiguration configuration) {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services) {
            services.AddMvc ().SetCompatibilityVersion (CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            var key = Configuration.GetSection ("AppSettings").GetSection ("SecretKey").Value;
            var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (key));
            services.AddTransient<AuthRepo> ();
            services.AddTransient<TalkRepo> ();

            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);

            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddCors (options => {
                options.AddPolicy ("EnableCORS", builder => {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin ()
                        .AllowAnyHeader ()
                        .AllowAnyMethod ()
                        .AllowCredentials ()
                        .Build ();
                });
            });

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure (IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
            if (env.IsDevelopment ()) {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage ();
            } else {
                app.UseHsts ();
            }

            app.UseCors ("EnableCORS");

            // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            //app.UseAuthentication ();
            app.UseMvc ();
            app.UseSignalR (builder => { builder.MapHub<ChartHub> ("/chat"); });

        }
    }
}
```

ChatController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CoreServer.Repositories;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace CoreServer.Controllers {
    [Route ("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ChatController : ControllerBase {
        private IHubContext<ChartHub> _hub;

        public ChatController (IHubContext<ChartHub> hub) {
            _hub = hub;
        }

        public IActionResult Get () {
            var timerManager = new TimerManager (() => _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync ("transferchartdata", DataManager.GetData ()));

            return Ok (new { Message = "Request Completed" });
        }
    }
}
```

When I use postman to connect, it does not have any problem.

When I use react using signalR to connect, it throws null error
this is what I got on react console.

```
[2019-11-01T14:06:13.729Z] Debug: Starting HubConnection.
[2019-11-01T14:06:13.730Z] Debug: Starting connection with transfer format 'Text'.
Error while starting connection: null

[2019-11-01T14:06:15.743Z] Error: Failed to start the connection: null
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:59:8 in error
- node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error
- ... 14 more stack frames from framework internals
```

=====================================================================================

this is what I have on dotnet core

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action CoreServer.Controllers.ChatController.Get (CoreServer) in 268.1478ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action CoreServer.Controllers.ChatController.Get (CoreServer) in 268.1478ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 598.9061ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 598.9061ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Can someone help me on this?

========================
Updated 11/01/2019

This is error log after updating services.AddSignalR(o => o.EnableDetailedErrors = true);

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://192.168.111.14:5000/api/chat  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://192.168.111.14:5000/api/chat  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
      Policy execution successful.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService:Information: Policy execution successful.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {action = "Get", controller = "Chat"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Get() on controller CoreServer.Controllers.ChatController (CoreServer).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {action = "Get", controller = "Chat"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Get() on controller CoreServer.Controllers.ChatController (CoreServer).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
```

This is expo error log

```
06
HubConnection {
  "cachedPingMessage": "{\"type\":6}",
  "callbacks": Object {},
  "closedCallbacks": Array [],
  "connection": HttpConnection {
    "baseUrl": "http://192.168.111.14:5000/api/chat",
    "connectionStarted": false,
    "connectionState": "Disconnected",
    "features": Object {},
    "httpClient": DefaultHttpClient {
      "httpClient": XhrHttpClient {
        "logger": ConsoleLogger {
          "minimumLogLevel": 1,
          "outputConsole": Object {
            "assert": [Function assert],
            "debug": [Function __expoConsoleLog],
            "error": [Function error],
            "group": [Function group],
            "groupCollapsed": [Function groupCollapsed],
            "groupEnd": [Function groupEnd],
            "info": [Function __expoConsoleLog],
            "log": [Function __expoConsoleLog],
            "warn": [Function warn],
          },
        },
      },
    },
    "logger": ConsoleLogger {
      "minimumLogLevel": 1,
      "outputConsole": Object {
        "assert": [Function assert],
        "debug": [Function __expoConsoleLog],
        "error": [Function error],
        "group": [Function group],
        "groupCollapsed": [Function groupCollapsed],
        "groupEnd": [Function groupEnd],
        "info": [Function __expoConsoleLog],
        "log": [Function __expoConsoleLog],
        "warn": [Function warn],
      },
    },
    "onclose": [Function anonymous],
    "onreceive": [Function anonymous],
    "options": Object {
      "WebSocket": [Function WebSocket],
      "logMessageContent": false,
      "logger": ConsoleLogger {
        "minimumLogLevel": 1,
        "outputConsole": Object {
          "assert": [Function assert],
          "debug": [Function __expoConsoleLog],
          "error": [Function error],
          "group": [Function group],
          "groupCollapsed": [Function groupCollapsed],
          "groupEnd": [Function groupEnd],
          "info": [Function __expoConsoleLog],
          "log": [Function __expoConsoleLog],
          "warn": [Function warn],
        },
      },
      "skipNegotiation": true,
      "transport": 1,
    },
  },
  "connectionStarted": false,
  "connectionState": "Disconnected",
  "handshakeProtocol": HandshakeProtocol {},
  "invocationId": 0,
  "keepAliveIntervalInMilliseconds": 15000,
  "logger": ConsoleLogger {
    "minimumLogLevel": 1,
    "outputConsole": Object {
      "assert": [Function assert],
      "debug": [Function __expoConsoleLog],
      "error": [Function error],
      "group": [Function group],
      "groupCollapsed": [Function groupCollapsed],
      "groupEnd": [Function groupEnd],
      "info": [Function __expoConsoleLog],
      "log": [Function __expoConsoleLog],
      "warn": [Function warn],
    },
  },
  "methods": Object {},
  "protocol": JsonHubProtocol {
    "name": "json",
    "transferFormat": 1,
    "version": 1,
  },
  "receivedHandshakeResponse": false,
  "reconnectPolicy": undefined,
  "reconnectedCallbacks": Array [],
  "reconnectingCallbacks": Array [],
  "serverTimeoutInMilliseconds": 30000,
}
INFO
10:06
[2019-11-01T15:06:19.386Z] Debug: Starting HubConnection.
INFO
10:06
[2019-11-01T15:06:19.388Z] Debug: Starting connection with transfer format 'Text'.
INFO
10:06
[2019-11-01T15:06:19.515Z] Debug: HubConnection failed to start successfully because of error 'null'.
INFO
10:06
Error while starting connection: null
ERROR
10:06
[2019-11-01T15:06:19.495Z] Error: Failed to start the connection: null

Stack trace:
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:59:8 in error
  node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error
  node_modules\@aspnet\signalr\dist\cjs\Utils.js:205:45 in log
  node_modules\@aspnet\signalr\dist\cjs\HttpConnection.js:306:40 in <unknown>
  node_modules\@aspnet\signalr\dist\cjs\HttpConnection.js:34:27 in step
  node_modules\@aspnet\signalr\dist\cjs\HttpConnection.js:7:65 in rejected
  node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
  node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in <unknown>
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:152:14 in _callTimer
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:200:17 in _callImmediatesPass
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:473:30 in callImmediates
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:337:6 in __callImmediates
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in <unknown>
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:314:10 in __guard
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:17 in flushedQueue
```

Comment: Try to change order of use: app.UseSignalR (builder => { builder.MapHub<ChartHub> ("/chat"); });    and app.UseMvc ();

Comment: It is the same.

Comment: Add services.AddSignalR(o => o.EnableDetailedErrors = true);  check if you have more details about the errors.

Comment: Can you post of client side?

Comment: And expo errors and logs

Comment: ChatScreen.js is client side

Comment: Add app.UseWebSockets(); before app.UseMvc() and rerun the server side

Comment: Nothing changed.

Comment: Try to Config client like this: const connectionHub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(hubUrl)
  .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
  .build();

Comment: Look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250252/react-native-app-wont-complete-negotiation-with-signalr-core

Comment: I can try to look at the problem with remote access.

Comment: I copied and pasted the linked source. it works. I am diagnosing. I changed client side and added services.addMvc(); Thanks for your kindness again.